# Having Issue on Running Dojo AMD on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dojo

I am trying to load some Dojo AMD Modules to ASP.Net MVC to `Home` contorller `index()` view as

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.18"></script>
<script src="~/Map/config.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="map-div" style="max-height:600px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the file directory looks like

[image]

as you can see I tried to keep all moudules in a custome folder called `Map`
in the `config.js` I have

```
(function () {
   console.log("------------> Config");
  'use strict';
   var pathRX = new RegExp(/\/[^\/]+$/)
    , locationPath = location.pathname.replace(pathRX, '');

  require({
    async: true,
    aliases: [
      ['text', 'dojo/text']
    ],
    packages: [{
      name: 'Map',
      location: locationPath + '../Map',
      main: 'map'
    }]
  }, ['Map']);

})();
```

but I am getting this error when I run the app:
[image]

Can you plese let me know why I am not able to load the `map.js` and it maps to

> http://localhost:50530/Home../Map/map.js

instead of

> http://localhost:50530/Map/map.js

Comment: Try `location: locationPath + '/../Map',`

Comment: Thanks  T Kambi but this is nit fixing the issue

Comment: isn't it just `location:  ../../Map` ?